# How to quote nested sub-shell arguments correctly?

Tags: bash, quoting

How to pass a string with spaces to a command which returns itself a string with spaces?

I tried the following four versions.

```
arg='one arg'

arg() { echo "arg: $1"; }

printf '1 |%s|\n' $(arg "$arg")
printf '2 |%s|\n' "$(arg $arg)"
printf '3 |%s|\n' "$(arg \"$arg\")"
printf '4 |%s|\n' "$(arg '$arg')"
```

They all fail:

```
1 |arg:|
1 |one|
1 |arg|
2 |arg: one|
3 |arg: "one|
4 |arg: $arg|
```

How to get this result?

```
? |arg: one arg|
```

Comment: Great question, by the way -- clearly asked, shows your intent, shows what you tried, etc. Thank you for the effort. :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

#### The Syntax

Using `$()` creates a new quoting context. Thus, double quotes *inside* a command substitution are completely independent of those outside it, and inside of closing the outer double quotes start a new and independent pair.

```
arg='one arg'

arg() { echo "arg: $1"; }

printf '? |%s|\n' "$(arg "$arg")"
```

...properly emits:

```
? |arg: one arg|
```

---

#### The Rationale (And History)

With the above syntax, adding additional nesting layers is easy:

```
printf '%s |%s|\n' "$(arg "$(arg "$arg")")"
```

With the pre-POSIX backtick syntax instead of `$()`, your attempt #3 would have been correct:

```
printf '3 |%s|\n' "`arg \"$arg\"`"
```

However, needing to backslash-escape both quotes and nested backticks gets unworkable quickly as your nesting depth increases. Adding just one more nested `arg` makes it:

```
printf '3a |%s|\n' "`arg \"\`arg \\\"$arg\\\"\`\"`"
```

Adding *two* additional layers (thus, three `arg` function invocations total) is even worse, getting you into:

```
printf '3b |%s|\n' "`arg \"\`arg \\\"\\\`arg \\\\\\\"$arg\\\\\\\"\\\`\\\"\`\"`"
```

Whereas with the modern syntax, it's just:

```
printf '3b |%s|\n' "$(arg "$(arg "$(arg "$arg")")")"
```

Much, **much** easier.

Comment: Note that the syntax highlighter is unaware of the new context, though. (Or at least, does a poor job of indicating it.)